# Owl carousal first slide video once finished then start the remaining slider images autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

My problem is owl carousal using home slider, images and including video also.
So we need first slider it's video playing, video time duration is (60sec+).
Once finish this video slider, then automatically start the remaining slider images.

Script :

```
var carousel = function() {
        $('.home-slider').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        autoplay: true,
        margin:0,
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        animateIn: 'fadeIn',
        nav:false,
        dots: false,
        autoplayHoverPause: false,
        items: 1,
        navText : ["<span class='ion-md-arrow-back'></span>","<span class='ion-chevron-right'></span>"],
        responsive:{
          0:{
            items:1
          },
          600:{
            items:1
          },
          1000:{
            items:1
          }
        }
        });
```